# Join query with different column types in "on" part

Tags: mysql, join

In need to make a JOIN on 2 tables based on columns which have different column types.

On table A, I have a DATETIME field and, on table B, I have a DATE and a TIME field, which combined would match the DATETIME field on table A.

What would be the recommended syntax for best performance on such join clause?

BD: MySQL 5.5.43-0+deb8u1-log

PD: Any extra info needed?

Comment: You are experiencing one reason not to split a DATETIME into two fields!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ADDTIME()` function:

```
tableA AS a JOIN tableB AS b
  ON a.datetime_column = ADDTIME(CAST(b.date_column AS DATETIME), b.time_column)
```

This might use an index on `tableA (datetime_column)` but not an index on `tableB`. The reverse might use an index on `tableB (date_column, time_column)` but not on A:

```
tableA AS a JOIN tableB AS b
  ON  CAST(a.datetime_column AS DATE) = b.date_column
  AND CAST(a.datetime_column AS TIME) = b.time_column
```

It won't hurt testing both versions. If one table is much larger than the other, then prefer to have the larger table's columns exposed (not cast) so their index might be used.

---

If you move to MariaDB (any version 5.3+) or MySQL 5.7 (when it's released), you can define a `VIRTUAL` column (or two) in one of the two tables to hold this conversion/calculation that can be persisted and indexed.

In 5.5, if efficiency is not good, which is expected with large tables, you could add a computed column yourself but it would have to be populated during inserts and kept in sync during updates by you (e.g. using triggers).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that approach, as I was just using plain CONCAT, with a space in between both fields, but didn't seem like the best way to do it

Comment: The `VIRTUAL` column sounds pretty interesting, sounds like mixing a `VIEW` into the `TABLE`

Comment: your edit on using indexes might trim down the rowcount for the join, I'll see what happens with that too

Comment: Yeah, which one to use will probably matter if you have some `WHERE` clause that restricts the number of rows from one of the two tables.

Comment: If you use `CONCAT`, you are essentially converting the columns from both tables to varchar. No index would be effectively used that way. The query will have to do either 2 full table scans or 2 full index scans.